# can't save metabox checkbox

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, meta-boxes

I m creating a plugin, i listed published pages with checkbox in my metabox. the problem is these checkbox values are not saved to DB.

```
function display_pages_metabox($post){ 
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $checkfield = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID, "checkfield", true) );

   wp_nonce_field( 'save_quote_meta', 'custom_nonce' );
   $pages = get_pages();

  foreach ( $pages as $page ) { ?>   
      <input id="page_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" type="checkbox" name="checkfield[]" value="<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" <?php if ( in_array($page->ID, (array) $checkfield) ) { ?> checked <?php } ?>/>

      <label for="page_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></label> <br>   
    <?php }
     }
function checkfield(){
    global $post;
    if(isset( $_POST['checkfield[]'] )){   

    $custom = $_POST['checkfield[]'];
    $old_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_checkfield[]', true);                    
        if(!empty($old_meta)){
            update_post_meta($post->ID, '_checkfield[]', $custom);
        } else {
        add_post_meta($post->ID, '_checkfield[]', $custom, true);
        }
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the php version?

Comment: change this `$checkfield = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID, "checkfield", true) );` to `$checkfield = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID, "_checkfield[]", true) );`

Comment: i changed but no luck :(

Comment: did you have add_action() for checkfield function ?

Comment: What have you done to debug this for yourself? Have you confirmed that the `$_POST` variable you are trying to add actually has a value? I suggest you do some research on how to process checkboxes that have multiple values....